# PowerMockitoExtension.class not found

Tags: gradle, quarkus, junit5, powermock, powermockito

I am using this for my new test cases

```
@ExtendWith(PowerMockitoExtension.class)
```

i have added dependencies in my grade as follow

```
testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit5:2.0.9'
```

Comment: Using `PowerMockito` and Quarkus has not been tested and is unlikely to work.

Comment: Hi @geoand 
Is there an alternative to PowerMockito that will serve the purpose for now?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.